# Django simple-apps template error - no StringUtil

Tags: django-templates, string-utils, apache-stringutils

I'm trying to use django basic apps from [this site](http://nathanborror.com/posts/2007/dec/2/django-basic-apps/) to make a basic blog work. It seemed to be going ok, but now the template keeps throwing an error saying "'stringutils' is not a valid tag library: Template library stringutils not found".
Sure enough, in the template in a number of places it says:

```
{% load stringutils %}
```

or

```
{% load stringutils comments i18n %}
```

I can't find mention of a stringutils template library anywhere, does anyone know what's going on?  Is it a standard package I need to install?  Or is it something specific to basic-apps that somehow didn't get put in?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's one of his template tags in the tools app

https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/tree/master/basic/tools/templatetags

you can take a look at what load does:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load

The second example you show is just him loading multiple modules in one statement.

looks like you need to add the tools app to your basic folder you made in your pythonpath, and add basic.tools to your installed apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, putting basic.tools in the INSTALLED_APPS fixed it.  Of course I then ran into another intractable problem with a template error but I'm hopeful I  can figure it out :)